# C# Error? An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#

It will give me this error when I try to hover over or click something like a button, I've try lot's of thing's please try to help? Here's my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace Login_Viper_Safe
 {
 public partial class login : Form
 {
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    private void bunifuThinButton22_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SlideA.Location = slideB.Location;
    }

    private void bunifuThinButton21_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        slideB.Location = SlideA.Location;
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Is it your real code? There are mistakes.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It is impossible for us to reproduce your issue with the only details beeing a 2-line explanation and a code block where everything but 2 nearly identical lines of code is pure Boilderplate. please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question, otherwise, no one will be able to help you

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Login_Viper_Safe
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bunifuThinButton22_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SlideA.Location = slideB.Location;
        }

        private void bunifuThinButton21_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            slideB.Location = SlideA.Location;
        }
    }
}
```